# Accessing host machine IIS Web Application via Win7 VM

Tags: iis-7, virtual-machines

I have a .NET development environment on my host machine which uses IIS 7 to serve the ASP application. I have loopback adapters set up to serve the website on 192.168.1.189 using the host file.

I am needing the ability to test this same web app using a VM with Win7 IE 8 on it, but I am having troubles getting the VM to see my host machine.  I tried going into the VM host file and pointing the website to my host machine like

```
192.168.1.189 www.mywebsite.com
```

However my VM cannot see this IP, which I tested using `ping`.  Any idea on what I need to change in order to get the VM instance to see and connect to my IIS server on that IP address? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could be using the host only vNIC, try creating either a NAT'd, Bridged or private network NIC.

Comment: create this from the VM or the host machine?

Comment: host machine -- what VM software you running?

Comment: VMware Player. And sorry not an expert by any means, so it may take some debugging. Is there a way to check if I am for sure using vNIC?

Comment: Check to see if you have "Virtual Network Editor" - I know it comes with vmware workstation. This will allow you to create virtual networks and bridge your vm's to your external network - this is easiest as you won't have to worry about DHCP scopes then.

Comment: You would probably be better of using something like Virtual Box if you don't want to buy VMware workstation (although it's worth every penny)

Comment: Doesn't look like I have it. Does it only come with the licensed version?

Comment: Oh ok thats what I figured.. So virtual box can do the same thing though?

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org Although both are as far as I'm aware Type 2 hyper visors so. You may have to recreate your virtual machine config but you can just reattach your virtual hard disks

Comment: Ok, well I just got VBox now. Anything special during configuration of the VM that I need to change?

Comment: For some reason VBox doesn't want to open my Win7 - IE8 image that I created from https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools.  I am going to download the files under VBox, even though I would have thought they were the same